# Google chrome doesn't respect default applications

Tags: google-chrome, default-programs

Is there a way to force chrome to respect my default applications?

I have `ristretto` set up as my default application to open png files, but clicking on a downloaded png in `chrome://downloads` opens a `imagemagick` preview.